# What is the name of this video defect?

Tags: video

I converted an avi file to mp4 using ffmpeg:

ffmpeg -i video.avi video.mp4

The resulting file I got is encoded using H264 but the video is flawed

This is the source AVI file (5 MB): [link redacted]

This is the resulting MP4 file (20 KB): [link redacted]

Does this defect have a name? The words that come in my mind is tear, tearing, bleed, bleeding, and melting - because the dark colors "fall" down.

Metadata - Video: MPEG4 Video (H264) 640x360 25fps 27kbps [V: h264 high 4:4:4 predictive L3.0, yuv444p, 640x360, 27 kb/s]

This is a screenshot of the video:

[image]

Comment: post some screenshot of single frames instead of links to the whole file, please. Also, metadata on bitrate and bit depth might be useful.

Comment: The defect is called a bad encoding. No way that a 5 MB video can be encoded into only 20 KB.

Comment: Well that really depends. If the 5 MB AVI file is uncompressed and just a static image, it is possible. // What is the exact resolution of the source file?

Comment: @harrymc 5 frames, 3 colors = 20kb. AVI instead has 5x25=125 uncompressed frames, which is humongously more. The mp4 file is perfectly fine. See my answer

Comment: Looks like a bug in the player when processing motion compensation.

Comment: I've redacted the links as they opened unwanted and potentially harmful popups. Questions should be self-contained. If linked material is needed, make sure that your links open directly the needed content, without any popups, advertising or anything similar. Thank you.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It's a **rendering issue**, not an issue of your video file. Use a different video player or update your codec library and your video player. This is a screenshot on my system:

[image]

MPC-HC is a discontinued player (see Edit March 2024), although on my system it renders fine. But if you are having issues with it, use VLC or something else.

**To answer your question**, there's no name for such defect, as it's not a video defect. It's impossible to say where on your system the problem arises.

**EDIT:**
In light of dirkt 's comment, here's a possible explanation:

> **Motion compensation block boundary artifacts**
>
> Block boundary
> discontinuities can occur at edges of [motion compensation](https://www.wikiwand.com/en/Motion_compensation) prediction
> blocks. In motion compensated video compression, the current picture
> is predicted by shifting blocks (macroblocks, partitions, or
> prediction units) of pixels from previously decoded frames. If two
> neighboring blocks use different motion vectors, there will be a
> discontinuity at the edge between the blocks.

Source: [Wikiwand.com](https://www.wikiwand.com/en/Compression_artifact#:%7E:text=perform%20error%20concealment.-,Motion%20compensation%20block%20boundary%20artifacts,-Block%20boundary%20discontinuities)

So, it can be that your player can't handle the discontinuity between the blocks in a sensible way.

### Edit March 2024

MPC-HC has [a new developer on Github](https://github.com/clsid2/mpc-hc/releases), and is now being continued.

Comment: Indeed, I opened the file in VLC and it works. Yet I can use a screen capturing program to record the MPC-HC playing it and to save it in a video with defects. By saving the same (Avisynth) source directly from Virtualdub2 in MP4, I get the same size, therefore the encoded size is small but realistic.

Comment: The screenshot is messed up in a way that can occur with bugs in BitBlt (ahem, probably not bit granular, so just plain bitting/copying of memory). As if they decided to a copy where source and dest overlap (eg if there was an animation effect (starting at the wrong end). Which can happen with broken coordinate arithmetic, possibly only at certain display/window sizes.